# I want to re render the list Component but with different props as a argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here I am calling the Function openProblem every time and want to re-render the list component with different prop arguments.

I have this.state and function calling but it didn't worked out.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import List from './demoList'
import './userHome.css'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class UserHome extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [],
        }
    }

    openProblem = (e) =>{

    console.log("difficulty = "+e.target.value)

    if(e.target.value==="Easy") {
        this.state.list =  [1,2,3,4,5]
    } else if(e.target.value==="Medium") {
        this.state.list = [6,7,8,9,10]
    } else {
        this.state.list = [11,12,13,14,15]
    }

    console.log("list = "+this.state.list)

    ReactDOM.render(<List list = {this.state.list}/>, document.getElementById('walla'));

   }
```

This is the List Component which I Want to render:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            list: this.props.list
        }
        // this.ShowProblemContent = this.ShowProblemContent.bind(this);
        console.log("inside demoList = ");
    }

    ShowProblemContent = (e) => {
        ReactDOM.render((e.target.value), document.getElementById('showProblemContent'));
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.list.map(item => (
                <button value = {item} onClick = {this.ShowProblemContent} key={item}>{item}</button>
                ))}
            </ul>
                // <button>{this.state.list}</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem you are facing in rendering, whether render didn't happens, or it is not happening after state is getting changed. can you put the code where you are calling the openProblem function

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where in your code you are calling `openProblem`, but in any case, React's `state` is [immutable](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc/). You should only change the state using `setState`, which means `openProblem` should look as follows:

```
openProblem = e => {

    console.log("difficulty = "+e.target.value)

    if(e.target.value==="Easy") {
        this.setState({ list: [1,2,3,4,5] })
    } else if(e.target.value==="Medium") {
        this.setState({ list: [6,7,8,9,10] })
    } else {
        this.setState({ list: [11,12,13,14,15] })
    }

    // setState is async, so this console.log might show outdated data.
    console.log("list = "+this.state.list)
}
```

Read more about React's state [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html).

Also, I dont know why you are calling `ReactDOM.render` in the component. The only place where you should call this function is `index.js`, to render the entire app into `#root`. In classic React components, you just have to implement the render function, so your final component should look like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import List from './demoList'
import './userHome.css'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class UserHome extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [],
    }
  }

  openProblem = e => {

    console.log("difficulty = "+e.target.value)

    if(e.target.value==="Easy") {
        this.setState({ list: [1,2,3,4,5] })
    } else if(e.target.value==="Medium") {
        this.setState({ list: [6,7,8,9,10] })
    } else {
        this.setState({ list: [11,12,13,14,15] })
    }

    // setState is async, so this console.log might show outdated data.
    console.log("list = "+this.state.list)
  }

  render() {
    return <List list={this.state.list} />
  }
}
```